# Synapse Serverless - Parallel queries limitations?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-synapse

I have *views* created in *Synapse Serverless* that point to the *delta tables* stored on *ADLS gen2*.

I am querying these views from the *Azure Functions* using the sample *pyodbc* code as mentioned below -

```
conn_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=<server>;DATABASE=<db>;ENCRYPT=yes;UID=<user>;PWD=<pwd>'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)

cursor_first_load = cnxn.cursor()
first_load_query = f"select * from gold.myTable where is_deleted = 0;"
cursor_first_load.execute(first_load_query)

if cursor_first_load.description is not None:
    <fetch the data and load to cosmos DB>
else:
    <do nothing>
```

I do the same thing for 10+ views *at the same time* and the results are random, sometimes it returns the whole data and loads it into the cosmos DB, and sometimes it goes to the else block (doesn't fetch the data at all).

Based on my research -

1. There is no concurrency limit on the *Synapse serverless SQL*, so queries are not getting queued.
2. I read from [https://celiamuriel.com/an-unusual-introduction-to-azure-synapse-analytics/#:~:text=It%20depends%20on%20the%20query%20complexity%20and%20the%20amount%20of%20data%20scanned](https://celiamuriel.com/an-unusual-introduction-to-azure-synapse-analytics/#:%7E:text=It%20depends%20on%20the%20query%20complexity%20and%20the%20amount%20of%20data%20scanned)  that the amount of data scanned might affect the concurrency. I have avg. 50k records in these views, and it should be scanning ~500k records at a time.
3. I also tried to select the views with a 1-minute gap to avoid any concurrency issues, still it is not able to fetch the data.

What could be blocking the queries?
Is there any other way to query the *Synapse Serverless views* in parallel and load data to cosmos DB?